# JAVA Validaciones de un String

Tags: java

realizo un programa  en el cual debo hacer lo siguiente:

En este problema haremos un "Hola mundo". Pero no lo hagamos tan simple. En vez de saludar siempre al mundo, saludemos a un listado de personas específicas.

Entradas
La primera linea de la entrada contiene un número N (1 <= N <= 100), representando el número de personas que debe saludar tu programa. A continuación aparecen N lineas, cada una con el nombre de una persona a saludar. Todos los nombres están en minuscula, conteniendo como máximo 10 caracteres entre la 'a' y la 'z', sin espacios.

Salidas
Por cada nombre de la entrada debes imprimir una linea saludando a esa persona. Si por ejemplo, la persona se llama "alfred", tu programa debe imprimir "Hola alfred". "Hola" siempre debe iniciar con H mayúscula, y debe haber un espacio entre "Hola" y el nombre. El nombre debe estar en minúscula, tal como se leyó desde la entrada.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema se debe a que no siempre el usuario digitara un nombre mayor a diez caracteres y estos caracteres no siempre seran letras minusculas(Ya saben como son los usuarios finales:))

¿Que debo hacer para cumplir con estas validaciones?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, usa el boton [edit] y pone tu codigo como texto. Las imagenes son dificiles de ver

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)